# WCF deny anyone without specific role using custom STS

Tags: wcf, wif, role, sts-securitytokenservice

I've made an STS by overriding SecurityTokenService and hosted it using WCF. Also I've created a relying party and test client. Client is successfully redirected to the STS (the program stops if I put a breakpoint in GetOutputIdentity method). Now I need to deny acces in my RP for all users except one role. How can I do it? Her is my configuraion:

```
protected override ClaimsIdentity GetOutputClaimsIdentity(ClaimsPrincipal principal, 
        RequestSecurityToken request, 
        Scope scope)
    {
        string authenticationType = principal.Identity.AuthenticationType;

        var outputIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType);

        outputIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        outputIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
        return outputIdentity;
    }
```

Relying party configuration:

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="IssuedToken" requireDerivedKeys="false" >
            <issuedTokenParameters>
              <issuer address="http://localhost:1318/Services/SecurityTokenService.svc">
              </issuer>
              <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:1318/Services/SecurityTokenService.svc/mex"></issuerMetadata>
            </issuedTokenParameters>
          </security>
          <httpTransport></httpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom [AuthorizationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate each call of RP. This class provide **CheckAccess** method that implement you custom validation according to incoming claims.